# Get the IPaddress of the computer in an Android project using java

Tags: java, android, ip-address, ip, android-ksoap2

I am using [ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) and i need to get the IP address using java so that I don't have to type it manually everytime.

What i mean by IP address is , for example if I do **ipconfig** using the command shell:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : f0::ed2:e3bf:8206:44%13
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.107 **<--THIS ONE**
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

The thing is am developing an android app, and the emulator has a different type of IP's than the machine's .
I need to get the machine's IP , how is this to be done?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf
                        .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Log.e(tag, ex.toString());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: While this does work, I was getting some false positives, I had to validate the ip address format with a regex, that seems to work in all of my use cases.

Comment: I tried this, and I found this same approach all over the web, but I don't believe this works.  Having only a network connection (not on wi-fi), I get two interfaces.  One is loopback, and the other is rmnet0 which I have read is the network interface.  With this code, I get the rmnet0 one as my local IP.  However, when I set up a webpage to spit out my IP when hit from a browser based on the request headers, the IP is dramatically different and it's the same one I see if I hit any of the 'what is my ip' websites in the browser as well.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

To get the Ipaddress of your android device you use this code.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
String ip = intToIp(ipAddress);

public String intToIp(int i) {

   return ((i >> 24 ) & 0xFF ) + "." +
               ((i >> 16 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
               ((i >> 8 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
               ( i & 0xFF) ;
}
```

Comment: What if they don't have WiFi enabled, just 3G?

Comment: @Matt I don't know but don't 3G connections provide an IP Address?

Comment: Yeah, they do, I was just wondering if this code would still work, that's all. :)

Comment: Hey this code does work for me.... However the returned string is has an incorrect order

Answer (score 2):

Try this link

http://www.droidnova.com/get-the-ip-address-of-your-device,304.html

also you can try this command **adb shell netcfg**

Answer (score 2):

```
InetAddress iA=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println(iA.getHostAddress());
```

---

**See Also**

- [`getHostAddress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29)

Comment: hey, what about the ip address of the server where this client connected to @JigarJoshi?