# How to detect changes in the network?

Tags: android, networking

I need to know how I can detect a switch in Wi-Fi networks, albeit automatically or manually, it doesn't matter. Is there some kind of intent being broadcasted throughout the system when a switch is detected? Or do I have to manually check if a new network is selected by calling a method on a ConnectivityManager?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect 3G or Wifi Network restoration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503561/detect-3g-or-wifi-network-restoration)

Comment: That question seems to answer how to detect if a network is connected or disconnected in general. I need to know when a switch between networks happened.

Comment: You can use the same code. If the type is Wifi, use NetworkInfo to get [EXTRA_](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) data. For example BSSID should be different for various WiFi n/ws

Comment: On a quick notice, that would involve caching the BSSID of the current network and comparing it with the new one if I am not mistaken? If so, I'd rather not, as I only need the update of a network switch to retrieve a new IP-Address... I don't need to know the BSSID of the network.

Comment: Yes, but that's the easiest way to tell

Comment: Either way, if there is a switch in WiFi networks CONNECTIVITY_ACTION should be broadcasted, call [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307992/get-the-ipaddress-using-java) to get the ip-address

Comment: I already know how to get the IP-Address, but thanks for the info though :)

Comment: Let me know if it works or if you find a different solution you can post it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this point in time, I have fixed this like this (haven't fully tested it yet as I don't have a second network available at the moment):

I extended the BroadcastReceiver class

```
private class NetworkSwitcher extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (!action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            return;
        }
        NetworkInfo networkInfo =
            (NetworkInfo)intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Network type: " + networkInfo.getTypeName() +
                        " Network subtype: " + networkInfo.getSubtypeName());
                getOwnIpAddress();
                mClient.updateUnicastSocket(mOwnAddress, mUnicastPort);
            }
        } 
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Network connection lost");
        }
    }
}
```

I register this class as a receiver with a filter set to the `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` intent (setting it in `onResume()` and releasing it in `onPause()`). This ought to catch any automatic Wi-Fi network switch. The `getOwnIpAddress` retrieves the device's IP address from the `WifiManager`.

I've also found that it works when I return to the activity from another activity.

Comment: I realize this is the accepted (by the OP) but I don't think it will work.  The docs recommend using WifiManager rather then ConnectivityManager for the sort of thing you describe, so you would use WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION, but I'm not sure if even that would do the trick: notifying you when your client roams from one BSSID to the next (if I understand the question correctly).

Comment: That actually might have been a better solution. Though I'm not working on this application any more (maybe again in the future though). If I had known of the WifiManager, I would have tried that as well.

Comment: `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` will do the trick exactly as @Tom said and mentioned in [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)